# How to access data from your application hosted on Heroku?

Tags: database, rest, heroku, zapier

I'm new to Heroku so not very familiar with it other than it's a service for deploying your applications and database hosting.

So I need to be able to access data from the application's database, how is this usually done?  Do I send a request to the database directly or do I have to go through application layer (and that is through an API?).

I want to be able to connect a Zapier to it to get the data out.

Comment: Assuming you're using Heroku Postgres, [just connect directly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#external-connections-ingress). Make sure you enable SSL and look up your credentials each time, though. They can change.

Comment: Is Postgres the standard out of the box with Heroku?  I read it can also take on MySQL, NoSQL databases but are those not coming with Heroku by default?

Comment: Nothing is out of the box. You get to pick what you use. Heroku has its own Postgres and Redis services. I believe all other data stores are third-party. Do you already have a database?